# MySQL - Combine rows into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I searched through various questions but I didn't find an answer.
I have a MySQL table 'teams':

```
+--+----+------+
|id|name|active|
+--+----+------+
|1 |bla |1     |
|2 |blu |0     |
|3 |croc|1     |
|4 |bold|1     |
|5 |foo |1     |
|6 |bar |0     |
+--+----+------+
```

and a table 'data':

```
+----+-------+----+
|team|project|time|
+----+-------+----+
|2   |some   |1   |
|2   |some2  |5   |
|3   |one    |16  |
|3   |one2   |100 |
|5   |more   |2   |
|5   |more2  |60  |
+----+-------+----+
```

In PHP I'm querying the data like this:

```
SELECT t.name, t.active, d.time
FROM teams t
RIGHT JOIN data d ON (t.id = d.team)
ORDER BY t.id
```

Everything works find and my result looks like this:

```
+----+------+----+
|name|active|time|
+----+------+----+
|blu |0     |1   |
|blu |0     |5   |
|croc|1     |16  |
|croc|1     |100 |
|foo |1     |2   |
|foo |1     |60  |
+----+------+----+
```

...but I want that my result looks like this:

```
+----+------+---+---+
|name|active|t1 |t2 |
+----+------+---+---+
|blu |0     |1  |5  |
|croc|1     |16 |100|
|foo |1     |2  |60 |
+----+------+---+---+
```

So... How can I reach this? I hope I have not overlooked an already asked question... :(

Thank you very much!

EDIT: First, thank you all, but I forgot something... It is also possible that e.g. one2 does not exist...

Comment: you don't. you want what's basically a pivot table, which mysql doesn't support. Do that transform in your client code instead. It **CAN** be written in sql, but it gets VERY ugly, VERY fast.

Comment: [Pivot table basics: rows to columns](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78), although I'd have to agree with @MarcB: it can get messy!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 SELECT t.name, t.active, 
 min(time) t1, max(time)t2
FROM teams t
RIGHT JOIN data d ON (t.id = d.team)
group by name
ORDER BY t.id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/608e1/5)

EDIT:

try this

```
   SELECT t.name, t.active, 
   min(time) t1, if  (  max(time) is not null and max(time) <> min(time) , max(time), null )t2
  FROM teams t
  RIGHT JOIN data d ON (t.id = d.team)
  group by name
  ORDER BY t.id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ca19/2)

Comment: he have already mentioned two records in his wished results `t1` and `t2` , if he have three he should mention also `t3`

Comment: @user2329363  and if one2 doesnt exist what result you want ??

Comment: It is possible, that the project 'one' exists, but the project 'one2' not. In this case 't2' should be null. But in your case 't2' has the value of 't1'.

Comment: echo_me Now I have another problem... It is also possible that 'one' doesn't exist but 'one2' does. Then 't1' should be null. How can I manage this?

Comment: my query is also working for this second suggestion, otherwise how you know if its t1 or t2 time value ?

Comment: The problem is, that if 't1' doesn't exists 't2' is displayed in 't1' and 't2' is null. But 't1' should be null and 't2' should display the value.

Comment: Did you understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If there cold be at maximum two rows for each team, I would use something like this:

```
SELECT
  teams.name,
  teams.active,
  min(d1.time) t1,
  max(d2.time) t2
FROM
  teams INNER JOIN data d1
  ON teams.id=d1.team
  LEFT JOIN data d2
  ON teams.id=d2.team AND d1.time<d2.time
GROUP BY
  teams.name,
  teams.active
```